# Magento 1.9.2.4 shortcode blocks no longer work

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks, permissions

I have two blocks currently on my cms pages  and they were working fine in magento 1.9.2.1 but neither want to display now after upgrading to 1.9.2.4 could someone please guide me to get them to work ?

I know 1.9.2.2 update patch requires them to be whitelisted via their name. I have added various names to this list via admin -> permissions-> block permissions. But, no luck.

current permissions:

[image]

Comment: What you have added post in question?

Comment: @PrashantValanda I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the var/log/exceptions.log file I found:

```
    2016-03-18T11:21:12+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined index: pagination  in /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/vish/default/template/pcarousel/pcarousel.phtml on line 48' in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
```

So I went to the pcarousel.phtml file and removed the line:

```
<?php if($crudata['pagination']==1){ ?> <p class="jcarousel-pagination"></p><?php } ?>
```

Done, the trick and now the extension looks to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelist block:

```
{{block type="companyname/modulename" name="myunique_name" template="mytemplate/mytemplate.phtml"}}
```

You need to add **companyname/modulename** for whitelist block.

Comment: {{block type="pcarousel/pcarousel" pcarousel_id="6" template="pcarousel/pcarousel.phtml"}} is my shortcode block. I have added pcarousel/pcarousel but not worked

Comment: Refresh cache? ....

Comment: @snh_nl tried many times, I am looking into the code and find that var_dumping this line returns blank, $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();